# Can i insert IF statements in Kendo Dialog actions?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, dialog

I'm trying to make a Kendo dialog pop-up. But i need to hide a button under a certain condition. Can i make an if statement somewhere in actions property or is there any other way to hide them from outside?

I know that you can do whatever in content property, but i was wondering if i can customize existing buttons. This is how i theoretically imagined it but it didn't work

```
 actions: [{
        if(link !=null) {
            text: linkName,
            action: function (e) {
                    window.location = link;
                    return true;
                },
        }
    }, {
            text: 'Закрыть',
            action: function (e) {
                Close();
                return true;
            }
        }]
```

Comment: you need to push / splice items to the actions array **before** rendering it. In a nutshell, the array should be provided with or without the item, but the condition should be **external** to the array itself.

Answer (score -1):

As briosheje said, you have to define array before rendering the widget, but you can update existing dialog's actions with setOptions method. You can check a basic example at https://dojo.telerik.com/EJefarON/8